# How do I stop falling for pump fakes while still denying shots?

Tags: nba2k12

It seems to be much easier to fall for a pump fake and thus resulting in a foul in 2k12 than 2k11.  My big man center dude is constantly in the air and falling on top of people at the slightest movement when all I want to do is to either jump straight up or keep my arms up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't hold down R2 when you block unless you know you need that extra power to jump over and bat the defender down.

Of course, you need to use turbo to get close, but R2 + Triangle is considered an intentional foul, espically when you have 7' Howard jumping and swinging through the air. So let go of R2 on DT and 1-on-1 and be patient, it'll come out. Blocking and rebounding are the hardest parts of the sport.